# React Components: Pass data between siblings on state change

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I am sharing an event in App comp between two child components

**App Comp**

```
class App extends Component {        
      constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { A : 'good'  };
    }    

 SharedEvent () {

 var newvalue =  this.setState({A:'update'}, () => {
    console.log(this.state);
    alert(this.state.A)
});
    }
      render() {
        return (        
      <div className="App">             
      <Content child1Event = {this.SharedEvent} text = {this.state.A}    
               child2Event = {this.SharedEvent} />            
         </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Parent comp**

```
render(props) {
    return (
      <div className = "App">           

      <Subcontent whatever = {this.props.child1Event} name = {this.props.text}  />

      <Subcontent2 whatever = {this.props.child2Event}   />    

       </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Child Comp**

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {  };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <button id = 'btn' onClick = {this.props.whatever.bind(this , 'shared')} > {this.props.name} </button>
    );
  }
}
```

subcontent2 is same as subontent

**I can successfully trigger sharedEvent from both components but it should change the name of button on setstate which it does not where am i wrong ???**

Comment: Why you're not passing `name` to `subcontent2`: `<Subcontent2 whatever = {this.props.child2Event}   />` ?

Comment: The scope is not more the same! Try changing `SharedEvent()` by `SharedEvent = () =>`

Comment: When you do `this.props.whatever.bind(this , 'shared')` where you are receiving this argument inside the `SharedEvent` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem can be from one of these two issues:

- First, you should replace your SharedEvent(){} function with SharedEvent = ()=>{...you function code} and it's because the scope has changed and if you are referring to **this** in your component for calling one of its functions, you should either use arrow functions or define them like you have done and bind them in your constructor to **this** which you have not done.
- Second, the onClick event on button, restarts the page by its default behavior and everything refreshes as does your component state, and this might be the cause that you do not see the text change because the page refreshes and the state gets back to 'good', so try replacing your onClick function with this:

  ```
  <button onClick={e => {e.preventDefault(); this.props.whatever();}}> {this.props.name} </button>
  ```

Comment: Mashallah you are great ! only the first step has solved the issue